# Terraform init │ Error: error configuring S3 Backend: no valid credential sources for S3 Backend found

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform

I am new to terraform and I am trying to configure CI/CD with github/terraform into an AWS EC2 instance.

I am using this video tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JwTP3wZHYnU

This is the error message I get when running "terraform init"
[image: This is the error message I git when running terraform init]

Here are the terraform files I created as per the tutorial (see 7:50 onwards)
[image]

Here is my encryption settings for the S3 bucket[image]

Any help greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

I think your AWS credentials are not properly configured. See my example bellow:

```
##############################
## Terraform default config ##
##############################
terraform {
  required_version = ">= v0.13"

  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source  = "hashicorp/aws"
      version = "~> 3.0"
    }
  }

  // TF state file
  backend "s3" {
    bucket                  = "terraform-prod"
    key                     = "terraform-prod.tfstate"
    region                  = "eu-central-1"
    shared_credentials_file = "../.aws/credentials"
    profile                 = "production"
  }
}
```

My AWS `credentials` file (do not forget do add it to .gitignore!):

```
[production]
aws_access_key_id = 123456789
aws_secret_access_key = 123456789

[staging]
aws_access_key_id = 987654321
aws_secret_access_key = 987654321
```